# Compiler doesn't report error in code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have made a mistake calling the function '. I spent a lot of time to understand why the compiler just ignores my function. Why it is not reported during compile time? The compiler builds everything without errors but tere is no messagebox with "2".

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>

void tstB()
{
MessageBox(NULL, "2", NULL, NULL);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
MessageBox(NULL, "1", NULL, NULL);
tstB;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The optimizer *loves* an expression like that.  Try `42;`  Same idea, different type.  Otherwise classic C syntax, any expression can be turned into a statement by putting a ; semicolon at the end of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not an error because it is a valid expression. The result of the expression is a function pointer. You could use the expression like this:

```
void (*p)() = tstB;
```

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing illegal about the use of `tstB;` as an expression, which is a valid statement. It's similar to

```
int main() {
    int a;
    a;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call it like this:

```
tstB();
```

Otherwise, you just have a pointer to a function, which is not an error.

With suitable compilation flags, GCC produces `warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]`